# Blocking vs. non-blocking DB access benchmarks

Tags: scala

Are there any benchmarks that pit a web application that uses JDBC for data access against one that uses non-blocking drivers?

Comment: This is probably the wrong forum to ask for this bit of knowledge. Do you have a more specific example for which you could ask a more specific question?

Comment: I think it's perfectly suitable to ask this question here with "scala" tag. Most Scala web frameworks use multiplexing approach and handle lots of connections with a limited number of threads. I'm wondering how blocking DB access layer will affect the performance. E.g in node.js or thin a blocking action will completely freeze the whole thing.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I believe it's too general. You should point out a specific stack (DB / connection pools). I hardly think somebody could have filled a complete report on all the possible configuration you can run on the JVM.